# Why is ANTLR not recognizing my numeral token

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm a total ANTLR neophyte; and trying my best to spike up on tech.

I'm at a loss to understand why my token defined as NUMERAL is not matching a number.

I'm sure this is some bone-headed move on my part but if it's something else (i.e. priority location of rules, etc.) I can definitely post my full lexer, but here is the token I'm having issues with:

```
DECIMAL_NUMERAL  : NUMERAL ('.' NUMERAL)?;
NUMERAL          : DIGIT+;
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9];
```

the text I'm using in Antl4-lab:  `actions+=/car.shift,if=tachvalue>3300`

and here is the full parser; I've trimmed it down quite a bit in order to locate the error:

```
parser grammar SimcParser;
options { tokenVocab = SimcLexer; }

profile : 
    (comment | action_base)*
    EOF;

action_base : 
    ( conditionalAction) NEWLINE;

comment : HASH SENTENCE NEWLINE;
actionpart : ACTIONS (DOT subName=IDENTIFIER)?;
conditionalAction :
    actionpart
    (OP_EQ | ASSIGN)
    actionName=dotted_name
    ACTIF
    exp;
    
dotted_name :
    IDENTIFIER (DOT IDENTIFIER)?;
    
eval :
BITWISE_OR | LT | GT | OP_EQ | OP_NOT | OP_LE | OP_GE;

exp :
  propertyName=IDENTIFIER eval qualifier
;

qualifier :
    NUMERAL;
```

and my resulting tree with the error.  Obviously I'm missing something big; as I though that the NUMERAL token (in qualifier) would catch a full numeric value with multiple digits but it does not.  It also doesn't work on a single digit. :
[image]

Comment: `DECIMAL_NUMERAL` can match anything that `NUMERAL` can and has priority because it comes first in your lexer grammar. So your lexer will never generate a `NUMERAL` token.

Comment: `qualifier : NUMERAL;`. Antlr4 parsers do not guide the lexer. The lexer works completely independently from the parser. It's best to just think that the lexer reads and tokenizes the entire input before the parser ever sees a single token.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep recognizing a `NUMERAL` besides a `DECIMAL_NUMERAL`, move `NUMERAL` above `DECIMAL_NUMERAL`:

```
NUMERAL          : DIGIT+;
DECIMAL_NUMERAL  : NUMERAL ('.' NUMERAL)?; // you can remove the `?` since this rule will never match a single `NUMERAL`
```

The way ANTLR creates tokens is as follows:

1. pick the lexer rule that matches the most characters
2. whenever 2 or more rules match the same characters, let the rule defined first "win"

Because input like `"123"` matches both `DECIMAL_NUMERAL` and `NUMERAL`, the order is important. Note that with my suggestion, the input `"123"` will now never become a `DECIMAL_NUMERAL` but always a `NUMERAL`! If you need to match any numerical token in your parser, combine the two in one parser rule:

```
number
 : DECIMAL_NUMERAL
 | NUMERAL
 ;
```